# Cannot complete Pull Request in TFS 2017 git repo

Tags: tfs, version-control

"Complete" button grayed out. Have set Allow for all branches, all users and all user groups. Have satisfied all branch policies. Any ideas what else to check?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are not part of any groups that have the complete privilege **Denied**.

In Azure DevOps, Deny trumps Allow.

Unless you're a member of the **Project Collection Administrators** group on your organization, membership in a group that explicitly **Denies** any permission will deny your permission, even if you are in another group that explicitly **Allows** you the permission and even if you as an individual user are granted **Allow** on that permission.

The **Contribute** permission is the one that should allow one to complete a pull request.

Please double check if Contribute permission is set to Deny in the **target branch** of pull request, please right click the target branch>Click Branch Security option like the following.

[image]